# Pretty printing does not seem to be working properly

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

These are a few lines of code I have written in my fla.

```
var phoneBookXML:XML = <phonebook><Name>Bobby Francis Joseph</Name><Age>25</Age><Sex>M</Sex></phonebook>;

phoneBookXML.prettyPrinting = false;
trace(phoneBookXML.toXMLString());

trace("*********************");

phoneBookXML.prettyPrinting = true;
trace(phoneBookXML.toXMLString());
```

The output from the output window is

```
<phonebook>
  <Name>Bobby Francis Joseph</Name>
  <Age>25</Age>
  <Sex>M</Sex>
  <prettyPrinting>false</prettyPrinting>
  </phonebook>
 *********************
<phonebook>
 <Name>Bobby Francis Joseph</Name>
 <Age>25</Age>
 <Sex>M</Sex>
 <prettyPrinting>true</prettyPrinting>
</phonebook>
```

Now if you see the prettyPrinting property does not seem to be working since both the ouput are same. My understanding is that content should  render without indentation or
any spacing. Any idea why this is happening so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prettyPrinting` is a static property. What you're actually doing is adding a property called `prettyPrinting` to the `phonebook` XML object.

Change your code to:

```
XML.prettyPrinting = false;
trace(phoneBookXML.toXMLString());
```

And it'll work